# Clone Azure active directory settings to another AD (tenant to tenant migration)?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I know that we can migrate a subscription from one Azure AD to another AD, and move a resource from one subscription to another subscription. Wondering can we clone the Azure active directory (tenant) as well?  like moving all/part of the AD roles, groups, settings, subscriptions and resources from one tenant to another?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to Migrate azure AD settings to other tenant.

you may submit your feedback here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm also been waiting for.